# Is there still a minimum height required for becoming a Lufthansa pilot?

Tags: flight-training, lufthansa

basically what the title says. Do I still need to be at least 165 cm to become a pilot or has this changed? There is no limit stated at their website but they also don't tell you that there is no limit.

Comment: Hello Sophia, welcome to aviation.stackexchange.com!

Comment: Wow, a 50th percentile European/North American female is 162 cm (5' 4"), Lufthansa is basically disqualifying half of all women automatically.

Answer (score 1):

This page for pilot applications shows a 165cm number.
I didn't translate to see what it's for

https://career.be-lufthansa.com/index.php?ac=search_result&search_criterion_activity_level=107

4 pilot jobs listed, only the first 3 show the 165cm.

Comment: Can confirm that those 3 are requirements to be taller than 165cm. The 4th is a posting to train as a pilot, no guarantee to be employed as one later (but one would assume good chances if you manage to get in the class)